# Recovery from kubectl crash

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-helm

What is the best way to troubleshoot when kubectl doesn't responde or exit with timeout? How to get it work again?

I'm having my kubectl as well as helm on my cluster down when installing a helm chart.

Comment: It is difficult to debug, If you are not able connect `kube-api`. That's why it is recommended to setup any logging solution at time you are deploying K8s cluster.

Answer (score 1):

General advice:

1. Check if your kubectl is connecting to the correct kube-api endpoint. You could take a look at your kubeconfig. It is by default stored in $HOME/.kube. Try simple CURL to make sure that it is not DNS problem, etc.
2. Take a look at your nodes' logs by ssh into the nodes that you have: see [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-cluster/#looking-at-logs) for more details instructions and log locations.

Once you have more information, you could get yourself started in the investigation of problems.